# pom.xml no Spring não está dando certo!

Tags: java, aplicação-web, spring, maven, pom

Independente da boot version fica me dando erro. 
será que alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver estes problemas de pom?

[image: Estou tentando aprender a usar o spring mas fica me dando erro no pom]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se já tentou isso mas tenta dar um "Force Update" do seu projeto Maven. Selecione seu projeto e execute um **Alt + f5** (ou clique com o botão direito > Maven > Update Project...), marque a opção:

> Force Update of Snapshots/Releases

E então dê OK. Tente isso algumas vezes se o problema continuar (as vezes o Eclipse "empaca").

Se não funcionar vá na aba **Problems** e delete o problema que estiver sendo relacionado com o Maven. Acredito que isso vá resolver o problema.

Espero ter ajudado.